# ImagePickerController immediately dismissed when launched from subview

Tags: ios, swift, presentmodalviewcontroller

I'm trying to present the ImagePickerController modally. My button firing the present action is inside a subview of the main view.
When pressing the button, the ImagePicker view is showing and dismissing right away.
I tried the same with another button which resides in the main view, and it's working fine.

My button action code:

```
@IBAction func pressUploadProfilePhoto(_ sender: Any) {
    picker.allowsEditing = false
    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Class deceleration:

```
class ProfileVC: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imagePicker.delegate = self            
    }
}
```

Delegate methods:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
    profilePicImg.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        profilePicImg.image = pickedImage
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
      dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

My Views hierarchy:

[image]

What am i missing?

Comment: where did u initialise the picker object?

Comment: Edited with Class deceleration and Delegate methods

Comment: What abt the lifetime of ProfileVC instance?

Comment: I'm quite new to ios development so it's possible that i'm not answering your question accurately, but the ProvileVC should be alive before, during and after the ImagePicker, and the only method I'm overriding in ProfileVC is the ViewDidLoad()

Comment: try to check you connections in the Connections Inspector. Maybe your button has more than one action

Comment: @Woof oh wow bingo! I don't know how, but the button was connected  both to the button action and the dismiss methods, thank you for thinking about it

Comment: Glad it helped. It is common problem for me, I'm always making miss-clicks doing connections =)

Answer (score 0):

```
Please Try the below code, may be your problem get resolved ->

1) Firstly add these Delegates in your Class.

class XYZ: UIActionSheetDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate

2) Create a variable ->
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

3) Set imagePicker delegate in viewDidLoad
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
}

4) Write Delegate Methods for UIImagePicker

// MARK: - ImageView Controller Delegate Methods

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            imageviewProfile.contentMode = .scaleToFill
            imageviewProfile.image = pickedImage

        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

5) Now your Action Method ->

@IBAction func pressUploadProfilePhoto(_ sender: Any) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
                imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
                imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
                imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Megha_Singh , I had steps 1-4 already implemented. i added your suggestion with `imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen` but it didn't help